# Using MouseListener to begin or end an otherwise infinite loop

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, awt

I want to have a mouseclick begin a loop that reports the location of the mouse and until the mouse is clicked. I had no problem beginning the loop and reporting the location, but even though the MouseClicked method ends the loop if the mouse is clicked twice, or should, the program continues the loop infinitely.

```
public JFramethingy() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        int numClicked;
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            numClicked++;
            for (int i = 0; i > -1;) {
                if(i % 1002000 == 0){
                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                int x = (int) b.getX();
                int y = (int) b.getY();
                System.out.println(x + "," + y); 


                }
                if (numClicked > 1){
                    numClicked = 0;
                    i = -3;
                }
                i++;
            }               
        }   
    });
```

Comment: When you click the mouse first time and the mouseClicked() method is called, it will keep looping infinitetly and would never return. Which means any other events including further mouse clicks will never be processed and hence your mouseClicked() will never be called again.

Answer (score 4):

Your infinite loop is happening on the EDT (that's what invokes the listeners), meaning that Swing can't process any more events. That means mouseClicked won't get called again, which is why numClicked isn't being incremented.

You need to spin the infinite loop off in a separate thread, and have the EDT only increment numClicked. Then you need to make numClicked volatile, or better yet, an AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no need to create a background thread *directly* as you can easily solve this by using a Swing Timer or javax.swing.Timer as this is just the sort of situation that it was built for.